# is there any kind of wildcard in sql to avoid updating certain fields?

Tags: sql, json

i just got a pre-defined DERBY query. Let's say the form inputs in the HTML are empty, if they are empty, i don't want them to be updated, like "skipped". I want to update only the ones != to "". Don't know if i'm being clear.

All i can imagine is to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET username = #[json:username], address = #[json:address]
   WHERE #[json:username] <> '' AND address <> '';
```

Can you guys help me with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't - you should build your query (or have three variations) based on the inputs.